# I'm having difficulty populating a new Javascript array from form values

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, creation, population

I have a form to collect Family information from a form which will eventually be used to enroll in a new benefit plan. I want to populate an array with the values required for each individual to be used to write the benefit record. Everything I've found so far simply creates array values and increments the index for each one. What i need to do is add multiple elements to each array index.

The initial code I tried doesn't work. I'm taking the values from the form which are there but when I try to create the array row it errors out
I need to know how to accomplish this

When I try to execute I get " Unable to set property 'fname' of undefined or null reference

I know I'm not doing this according to Hoyle but I can't seem to find the correct method. 
How do I do this.

```
function ValidateChgFAM()
{   
   formObj = self.MAIN.document.SSform2;

   var Fname = formObj.FirstName11.value
   var Lname = formObj.LastName11.value
   var Gender = formObj.Gen11.value

var famMbrs = new Array();
    famMbrs[0].fname = formObj.FirstName11.value
    famMbrs[0].lname = formObj.LastName11.value
    famMbrs[0].gender = formObj.Gen11.value
    famMbrs[0].birthdate = formObj.Birthdate11.value
    famMbrs[0].seq = "01"
```

When I try to execute this I get the message " Unable to set property 'seq' of undefined or null reference.

I don't live with Javascript but I've been work with this system and I can normally figure stuff out.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler and more elegant solution:

```
const famMbrs = [];

const member = {
  fname: formObj.FirstName11.value,
  lname: formObj.LastName11.value,
  gender: formObj.Gen11.value,
  birthdate: formObj.Birthdate11.value,
  seq: '01'
}

famMbrs.push(member)
```

Will result in:

```
Array(
  0: {
    fname: (value),
    lname: (value),
    gender: (value),
    birthdate: (value),
    seq: '01'
  }
)
```

Comment: Ok, the code above would be only the first of several (potentially 12) sets in the array. so to create the next is it just a matter of recreating the member construction?

Comment: Ok this didn't work as expected.  It gets to "const member = { and throws the error "Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference" What could be the problem here. I know all the values are available: btw thanks for your help

Comment: It means one of the values it is trying to find doesn’t exist. Log all your form values to console and find out which one is throwing the error.

Comment: Yes I figured that out.  I was able to resolve that issue (the birthdate) by setting the value to a variable and then passing the variable in const. However, I'm not able to query the value of the array row.  Also I will be adding more rows to the array and not sure how that will work.

Comment: Can you address the other questions. I've managed to create two rows (i think). "famMbrs.length" reports a value of 2. However I seem to be unable to read back any of the data. "famMbrs[0].fname.value for example returns a "cannot read property "value" of undefined. similarly I have tried referencing "member" and "member1' with the same result. I think I've stored the data but if I can't retrieve it later in the program I might as well not have built this.

Comment: @capndave You don't need `.value` when querying the `famMbrs` array. E.g. `famMbrs[0].fname` is enough to retrieve the value.

Comment: Thank You.  That did it (Old habits die hard). I will definitely remember this.